# Github python gitignore, why is c extension ignored? Is there a better way to use C in Python?

Tags: python, github, gitignore

Recently I pushed a Python package to github, and I noticed that all `.so` files are not uploaded.

And in the default `.gitignore`, I found out

```
# C extensions
*.so
```

Why?

I'm not familiar with C++, and I was told that the `.so` files are created with `pybind`.

Does this mean that there is a better way to use C++ code in python?

Comment: Source Control Management systems are for _source code_. A `.so` file is basically compiled `.c` or `.pyx`, which should not be committed to the repo. That being said, if you want to include a third party `.so` file in your project you can remove that line from `.gitignore` or use `git add -f` to force add that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any file that can be re-generated after cloning your repository should be ignored.
(and they are indeed ignored by a [python-based `.gitignore`](https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/python))

This is not limited to *.so files, but applies also to any file in distribution *folder* (`dist/`) or cache folder (`__pycache__/`)

That promotes a source dependencies (meaning you include the C sources in your repository, as well as a Makefile allowing to quickly rebuild the C artifact)